# Can a ghost nuke from within a bunker?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that marines and marauders can stim while in a bunker, but can a ghost use a nuke while in a bunker? My thought is this might be very effective for defending against an attack, and will buy the ghost time to drop the nuke, even when the enemy knows where he is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, only stim can be used in a bunker.

Medics will heal units they are sharing a bunker with.

Comment: Is this true in multiplayer too? I'm only asking because you mention medics, and they are one of the many differences between single and multiplayer. Just want to make sure this isn't one of them.

Comment: this is also true for multiplayer

Answer (score 2):

No, ghosts can only nuke outside the bunker, this may be due to the way they have to target the nuke. Bunkers only protect your men and give them 1+ range boost.

Comment: Having Stim in Bunkers is an exception because it was added as a skill for Bunkers. All other units in Bunkers cannot use any abilities except for auto-cast abilities like singleplayer medics and SCV repair.